# Laravel normal login with vuejs using axios returns error Request failed with status code 422

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Am trying to use laravel and vue js with axios

Previously this was my login form

```
<form name="login-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
 //username and password fields

</form>
```

Which works perfectly one can login

Now i would like to use vuejs in a similar way without making my app a single page app

so i have resulted to making a login component

```
 <template>
  <form name="login-form">
    <input type="email" v-model="email" class="form-control" autofocus>
    <input id="password" type="password" v-model="password"  required>

     <button type="submit"
             class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"
             @click.prevent="login" 
            :disabled="disableform">
            {{submitted?"Logging you in .....":"Login"}}
     </button>

  </form>
 </template>
```

Now script part

```
  <script>

    export default {
      data: () => ({
         email :'', password:'', remeberme:true, submitted:false
      }),
    methods: {
    login() {
     //do other stuff like disabling buttons...etc
     axios.post("/login", {email:this.email, password:this.password})
        .then(
            (res)=>{

              ///showing sweet alert then 
              // settimout for 3 sec the 
            window.location.href="/dashboard";
            },
            (err)=>{
             //show sweet alert of failed login
            }
        )
},
```

}

Now whenever i make the login post request an getting an error

```
Request failed with status code 422
```

I would like to proceed with the laravel vuejs workflow(with authentication sessions) but not an api jwt token request format.

What could be wrong or is this possible?

Comment: Did you add your csrf token to the request?

Comment: Yes in my bootstrap.js its already set even checking on the developer tools i can see it as X-CSRF-TOKEN:Gok4MlG3zgp95ic2tkDntQy9nOHTUsJoWE4PnXsh

Comment: let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');  window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;

Comment: so csrf tokn is already there

Answer (score 1):

It's a validation error. check you laravel controller regarding post/put function.

```
Request failed with status code 422
```

When laravel fail the validation then it appears.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a csrf_field in your form, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="csrfToken">
```

And define it in your script:

```
data() {
   return {
      csrfToken: ''
   } 
},
created() {
       this.csrfToken = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
}
```